# Is there a way to use JQuery style selectors against XML/HTML in C#?

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, xml

I have need of a string-based method of selecting nodes from XML

**I know about XPATH**, I'm looking for an alternative

What I would like is JQuery/CSS-selector style XML traversal and node selection. Are there any libraries out there like that for .NET? Preferably open source.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, I found my own answer:

[CsQuery](https://github.com/jamietre/CsQuery) which is open source on GitHub allows just what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

[Linq to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) is pretty good at it. It's even more natural than jquery imho.

Comment: Linq to XML isn't really string-based though. That's compiled code. I need to be able to store a string that tells code where to look in an XML blob.